# Nginx server_name issue on HTTPS for multiple applications(vhosts)

Tags: nginx, https

I have two application on server which where were working perfectly until I planned to switch them to HTTPS.

Nginx config for app 1:

`server_name abc.com my.abc.com static.abc.com`

Confing for app 2:

`server_name _;`

Before enabling SSL both apps were working e.g.

App1 `http://static.abc.com/some-assets.png`

App2 `http://static.def.com/some-assets.png`

After enabling SSL

App1 `https://static.abc.com/some-assets.png`

App2 `https://static.def.com/some-assets.png`

If I try to access App2 `https://static.def.com/some-assets.png` now is also pointing to App 1 somehow.

I tried to dig out and found if I replace `server_name _;` with `server_name static.def.com;` in App 2 Nginx config its start working.

My question is it required for Nginx to explicitly define the domains if you want to serve them over HTTPS? Or is it something with SSL handshake is failing etc. and its ends up like this?

Update:

Nginx Config Files:

[abc.conf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PGJ1m9cAodTFdhcWM5SllsNEk/view)

[def.conf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5PGJ1m9cAodYjZDSW5NbWtNazA/view)

Comment: You should describe your problem better. Could be that your https certificate doesn't apply to all the domains in your server_name line. I define a separate server block for each https website. Two actually, as the non-www forwards to the www version.

Comment: I updated question could be easy to understand now. I have two server blocks for both websites. The only difference is explicitly defining the domain in nginx `server_name` i.e. `server_name _;` and `server_name abc.com my.abc.com static.abc.com`

Comment: Please include the actual Nginx site configuration file, a better description of your error, applicable logs, and ideally curl showing response headers.

Comment: How did you "enabled SSL"?

Comment: updated question with ngix configs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Johannes said, I think you have a misconception of what `_` mean as a `server_name`: absolutely nothing. Most guides include it in their default catch-all server so as to be sure that it doesn't interfere with any named virtual server.

What you must have missed in what you're reading (or maybe the people who wrote what you're reading missed it) is that a proper default server actually includes the `default_server` option as part of the `listen` directive. Read nginx.org/r/listen for more information.

Comment: thanks, i have `default_server` updated question have a look at nginx configs

Comment: Well yes, it is your default server for requests on port 80 but not on port 443 so of course NGINX's behavior is inconsistent when switching over to HTTPS.

Comment: Ah! ok that's could be the evil. Means if I change 

`listen 443 ssl defualt_server;`
Should be fine?

Comment: Yep! That should do the trick.

Comment: Yep! that's was the problem.. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on the order of your server definitions. `_` is no special name, it is just an invalid domain and therefore will never match. That makes is the same as the server names in the other server definition for a host like `static.def.com`: Both don't match.
If there is no match at all, nginx will simply take the first server definition.

Comment: if there is no match and it takes the first server definition, then why its working with HTTP and not working with HTTPS. And I'm having two different `.conf` for both applications in `nginx/conf.d`

Comment: updated question with nginx configs, you can have a look!

Comment: Nginx merges all config files together into a single configuration set, so there is no real separation by putting it in different files (just helps you organize).

Comment: offcourse, just to give you how its organized.